# Find the cell in google sheet with the conditions

Tags: google-sheets

Hey guys thank you so much for your help.
I am not good in English, so if I have mistakes in grammar or vocabulary, please forgive to me.

I have a problem with google spreadsheet. 
I have 2 table (in this picture). I want to get the value of the cell in table 1. But the result have value "TRUE" in table 2 and the value in table 1 is not NULL (in the same column).
You can see in this picture. Room "A" in table 1 has value "m" in column B and has value TRUE in column B. So I get value "m". But Room "B" has value "n" and "i" in column B and C, but in table 2, Column B and C in row 9 (Room B) has value FALSE. So the result is null...
I don't know how to solve this problem. 
This is my spreadsheet. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TwDdq9q8vBn1Afk9MWrZYbK-89ksBAlM/view?usp=sharing.

I am looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you so much.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After removing the contents of the cells B15:B18 try this formula in B15

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(A15:A18,  split(transpose(split(textjoin("¬", 1, if(B8:D11, A2:A5&"_"&B2:D5,)), "¬")), "_"), 2, 0)))
```

and see if that works?